# O que é essa "Time travel!"?

Tags: debate

Hoje abri o StackOveflow e quando entrei em uma pergunta, apareceu esse tema diferente, com a opção "Time travel!" para voltar para o padrão:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que é isso? Algum evento ou comemoração?

Comment: Que dia é amanhã?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/326036/401803

Comment: @bfavaretto é que hoje ja é amanhã em alguns lugares :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Foi um evento de primeiro de abril que trazia a internet de volta pras "vibes" dos anos 90, onde ter gifs, coisas piscando, etc era sinal de site grande, bem desenvolvido hehehehehehe... pra desativar era só clicar num ícone de relógio próximo do seu ícone de usuário... mas era bem maneiro, sinto falta rs

Answer (score 3):

### Eventooohh Nadaaaahhh!!!! Elah Foi Hackiada Pelos Heckers Anonemous xD o.o o.o :O

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Agente so queremos brincar, há há

> Mas falando sério, é uma brincadeirinha de primeiro de abril. De fato, bem planejada e engraçada. Se quiser voltar ao normal, só clicar no botão `Go to the future` ao lado esquerdo da página.

Comment: Lado esquerdo? Pra mim aparece um ícone de relógio na parte de cima e no lado direito, entre a pontuação/badges e o ícone do Inbox...

Comment: @hkotsubo onde fica o novo menu, em baixo do Under Construction

Comment: Ah, é que eu desabilitei o menu lateral nas preferências. De qualquer forma, o relógio tb aparece, então tem dois jeitos de voltar para o futuro... :-)